# jquery rating stars display at top when put in for loop

Tags: jquery, rating

My problem is with the JQuery star plugin. I have a number of reviews which have ratings.  But whenever I put the code in for loop, all the stars for all the reviews are displayed at the top at once. My test code is like follows:

```
{% for rec in recent %}                 
Rating:
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="1" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="2" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="3" disabled="disabled"  checked="checked"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="4" <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="5" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="6" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="7" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="8" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="9" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="10" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="11" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="12" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="13" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="14" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="15" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="16" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="17" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="18" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="19" disabled="disabled"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" name="test-4-rating-6" value="20" disabled="disabled"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I have checked value 3 just for test purposes.

I even tried calling from javascript like so `('input').rating('select','3')`;

I am using the 5 star rating as per the demo in http://www.fyneworks.com

At once meaning-for example I have 12 reviews displayed on the page. Each review has the review text and some fields and the rating. At once meaning instead of displaying the 5 stars for each review it displays the rating stars for all the reviews at the top of the page. That means at the top of the first review I have like 5*12=60 stars displayed.

For the life of me I dont know why its acting like that. The css file for the jquery star rating is also given on the site. There isnt much documentation about issues.

I would really appreciate any kind of help..even suggestion to other rating plugins would help!

Comment: " for all the reviews are displayed at the top at once "  what that mean. give an example . if you select 8 what is happening

Comment: My guess is that it is a CSS issue related to absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion to another rating plugin: [download RateIt](http://rateit.codeplex.com), [view examples](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm)